# I was sitting beside the road and I saw a bus coming from AHEAD or FRONT

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

[image]

> 1. *I was sitting beside the road and I saw a bus coming from ahead*
> 2. *I was sitting beside the road and I saw a bus coming from the front*

My friend: Which direction is the bus coming from?
Myself: **From the ahead or front?**

Is the phrase in bold not grammatical?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to write?

Comment: Why not simply "I saw a bus coming"? In so far as one's eyes are at the front of one's head, then I think it could be taken for granted that you saw the bus in front of you. As the bus is "coming" rather than "going" then I wouldn't use the word "ahead" - not that it is idiomatic in that way anyway.

Comment: Ok, I see you are trying to add a picture. (We can fix this.) But what is your question? If you are just trying to share a „funny“ picture, this will be removed soon.

Comment: Please take the [tour], browse the [help] and maybe [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be the better place.

Comment: Picking the best phrasing depends on what you're trying to achieve. Please provide some context to clarify. You can do this via the [edit] link.

Comment: I would say "down the road" or "up the road"

Comment: What exactly would you like to know? **1.** If the sentence in the image is grammatical? **2.** If your 2 versions (you changed the tense) are grammatical? **3.** If we should say the "bus is coming the ahead" or "front"? **4** Do you want to know if this idea is written in good clear English? Please try to tell us.

Comment: The kid in the picture is sitting at the side of the road NOT FACING the road. "The bus came from ahead" would indicate the bus drove from offroad towards the kid.  ---- If the kid instead sat TOWARDS the road, it would be informative  to say "The bus came from the left/right" - "the bus came from front" would be ungrammatical either way, "the bus came from the front" might indicate a nearby warzone, the information in "the bus came from ahead" would depend on whether the kid was looking left or right at that moment, but it would be grammatical.

Comment: Whoever annotated the picture is not a native English speaker. "I'm sitting beside the road and a bus _is_ coming _towards_ me" is colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

As two people before me have said, it would be correct to either say that the bus is coming from the left/right, or that it was coming towards the subject. Furthermore, when talking about an object approaching a place from another, there is geographically / geometrically NO existing "front." An example of this would be a forest. there is no "front" of a forest, just starts and ends. This would be different if we were talking about a house or a building, or other man-made structure with designated sides, in which one side would be the designated "front." If that were the case, you would have to be sure to clarify the front of what place or object. Example: "it came from the front" is incorrect, while "it came from the front of the building" is correct.